# Android Static Method or create an Instance of Class

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

This is a question I should know the answer to, but I would be interested in knowing both the best way to create a List in Android and why.

I need to create a somewhat large list with a few dozen entries, so I would prefer not to do it in the activity that will use it (although I can if it's the fastest and safest method, it just adds code to an already large activity).

Should I create a class:

```
public class CreateList(){
    List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Object> createList(){
        myList.add();
        myList.add();
        ....
        ....
        return myList();
    }
```

And use it by creating an instance of the class in Android Activity:

```
CreateList cL = new CreateList();
neededList = cL.createList();
```

OR

Is it better to use a static method:

```
public class CreateList(){


    public static List<Object> createList(){

        List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add();
        myList.add();
        ....
        ....
        return myList();
    }
```

and call it more simply:

```
neededList = CreateList.createList();
```

Does the static method have memory leak issues? Is one way better?

Answer (score 0):

The second one is better implementation as it promotes SOC(Separation Of Concerns) also it can promote code reusability but if you're gonna do business logic code, its better to do it using ViewModels. Please see https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1

Doing your business logic code on the main thread with huge chunks of data might have the tendency to block the main thread thus a delay happens on the UI.